# C# WinUI project, How to add Multiple ExpressionAnimation on same control?

Tags: c#, uwp, winui-3, visual-studio-2022

Im starting to get into some animations for some specific buttons, basically what im doing right now im struggling to find the proper way to insert multiple expression animations for the same control.

If i only call button1.StartAnimation("some expression animation reference") once, works as intended, however as soon as im trying to start a second animation button1.StartAnimation("a second expression animation reference") the program crashes imediately with error System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

What im trying to do is to use multiple expression animations for the same control to update different properties at the same time.

My question is simple, how can i execute multiple expression animations on the same control at the same time, OR how can i have an expression animation run multiple expressions and updating multiple target properties

Here is the code that im trying to execute:

```
        ExpressionAnimation anim1 = _compositor.CreateExpressionAnimation();
        anim1.Expression = "-((self.Scale.X - 1) * (self.ActualSize.X * 0.01) * 50)";
        anim1.Target = "Translation.X";

        ExpressionAnimation anim2 = _compositor.CreateExpressionAnimation();
        anim2.Expression = "-((self.Scale.Y - 1) * (self.ActualSize.Y * 0.01) * 50)";
        anim2.Target = "Translation.Y";

        
        anim1.SetExpressionReferenceParameter("self", button1);
        anim2.SetExpressionReferenceParameter("self", button1);
        

        button1.StartAnimation(anim1);//adds just fine and works as intended
        button1.StartAnimation(anim2);//crashes instantly with error System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'
```

PS: I know i can probably use a vector for position and use a single expression but what i really want is to understand how can i use more expressions to update multiple target values for same control.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i execute multiple expression animations on the same control at the same time,

I'm afraid you can't execute multiple animations like above that will make the second animation can't use the control that used by the first one.

For execute multiple expression, we suggest you use `+` to [combine together](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/animations/expressions#expressionAnimation-overview).

For example

```
_parallaxExpression = compositor.CreateExpressionAnimation(
 "(ScrollManipulation.Translation.Y + StartOffset) * ParallaxValue - " +
"(ScrollManipulation.Translation.Y + StartOffset)");
```

Comment: Greetings, thank you for your reply, i have a few questions regarding this method, it semms to me that, you are joining 2 strings into 1, how then would it get divided into 2 expresions? isnt ("some string" + "another string") still only 1 string?

How would the compositor know where to split the 2 expressions?
Secondly, how can we then update lets say 2 different Target variables (1 per expression)?

Im really curious about this solution.
Thank you in advance for your reply!

Comment: I have to say. for your scenario the better way is use vector to approach that you mentioned above.